# Migrating questions to any StackExchange site

Tags: support, feature-request, migration

When voting to close a question, you can vote to close a question because it "belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" (Closing > Off Topic > Migration), but the only options here are for [Math Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com), [Stats](https://stats.stackexchange.com) and [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com) . However occasionally I find myself wanting to refer people to a different StackExchange site, most recently [DataScience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/), [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), and [TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Is there an option for this in the current close menu? And, if not, maybe it would be good to include this in the Migration' part of the menu, possibly in the same way as the Duplicate menu with a text box to search for a relevant site.

Comment: See [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3853/11619) for more about this. FYI Grace Note works for SE, so what they say carries a lot of weight. The numbers may have changed in five years, but "migration via flagging" works reasonably well.

Comment: Apropos!  I want to remind you that requests (via flagging) for migration by a diamond moderator are MUCH more credible when the flagger actually knows more about the suggested receiving site. As in, they actively participate there. Migration requests "on a hunch" (yeah, that sounds fitting)  give me a headache. We don't want to dump our garbage on somebody else's lawn. And I don't know about the norms of, for example, CrossValidated at all.

Comment: In lieu of recommending migration or reposting a Question at another Community, I prefer (unless I'm active on the other site and know its on-topic parameters well) to suggest (by Comment) the examination of previous Questions at that site, giving one or two examples of what I find there that seems relevant.

Comment: @hardmath That's pretty much what I've been doing - posting links to the sites I think might be relevant and suggestiong the OP asks their question over there. I don't tend to go as far as to link them to specific questions though

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks, that makes a bit of sense now

Answer (score 8):

No, there is no such option available to users (but moderators can migrate anywhere). Migration paths to other sites are purposefully limited to a very small number of sites where the need for migration arises frequently and it is reasonable to assume that there is a sufficiently large pool of users that are familiar with the standards of that site.

If you come across a question that you think should be migrated to a site not available in the menu, vote to close it with a custom close reason saying this ("off-topic", "other") and flag the question for moderator intervention requesting the migration.